# Reporting Services - Passing LIKE statement in the url

Tags: .net, url, reporting-services, filter

im trying to pass a filter to generate report using Reporting Services in .NET.

I'm trying to pass a LIKE statement, something like

```
filter=(ordNumber LIKE '%52%')
```

so i run

```
reportUrl = serverData.rptOrder_Path
                .replace("#format#", "PDF")
                .replace("#sort#", "ordNumber")
                .replace("#filter#", currentFilter);

            window.open(reportUrl);
```

where the currentFilter is my like statement

**THE PROBLEM**

what i want:

```
Command=Render&Rs:Format=PDF&sort=ordNumber&filter=(ordNumber LIKE '%52%')
```

what i get:

```
Command=Render&Rs:Format=PDF&sort=ordNumber&filter=(ordNumber%20LIKE%20%27R%%27)
```

I know that browsers automatically replace **spaces** with **%20** but its chaging my '%52%'

Any ideas on how to get it right?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*SOLVED*

passed my link to server side and used C# to do my job with:

```
var encodedFilter = Url.Encode(whereString);
```